# initializing multiple drop support for the same view

Tags: java, swt

How to use two different drop support in one view itself with different transfer types?

```
    int srcOps = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY;
    Transfer[] dragDropTransfers = new Transfer[] { myTransferType1.getInstance() };
    this.getTreeViewer().addDragSupport(srcOps, dragDropTransfers, new OverviewDragSourceAdapter(this));
    this.getTreeViewer().addDropSupport(srcOps, dragDropTransfers, new OverviewDropAdapter(this));
    dragDropTransfers = new Transfer[] { myTransferType2.getInstance() };
    this.getTreeViewer().addDropSupport(srcOps, dragDropTransfers, new AddDropAdapter(this));
```

It gives org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Cannot initialize Drop.

Comment: Instead of lengthy descriptions of what your code does, it would be more helpful to extract a [mcve] and post real code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally `addDropSupport` uses `DropTarget`. The JavaDoc for `DropTarget` says:

> ERROR_CANNOT_INIT_DROP - unable to initiate drop target; this will
> occur if more than one drop target is created for a control or if the
> operating system will not allow the creation of the drop target

So you cannot use multiple calls to `addDropSupport`. You will have to write a single `DropTargetListener`

Comment: Is the very last sentence true? The documentation for `DropTarget.addDropListener()` explicitly refers to a *collection* of listeners.

Comment: @AndyThomas The problem is using multiple viewer addDropSupport calls, each call uses a separate DropTarget class instance which doesn't work.